# Get store in a ViewController

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewcontroller

Is it possible to retrieve a store from within a `ViewController`?
I'm trying to dynamicaly populate a toolbar with buttons from a store, but I'm not sure how to access the store from the controller.
Any hints appreciated.
My Extjs version is 5.1.

**View:**

```
Ext.define('EurocampingsCMS.view.Foo', {
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
    alias: 'widget.foo',
    requires: [
        'EurocampingsCMS.controller.Foo'
    ],
    controller: 'foo',
});
```

**ViewController:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Foo', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.foo',

    control: {
        '#': {
            beforerender: 'onBeforeRender'
        }
    },

    onBeforeRender: function (toolbar, eOpts) {

        //How to get store here??

        store.each(function (record) {
            toolbar.add({
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: record.get('localeId'),
                text: record.get('label')
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best would be to fully utilize MVVM architecture and define the store in viewmodel `stores` object. Then it is easy:

```
onBeforeRender: function (toolbar, eOpts) {
    var store = this.getViewModel().getStore('yourstorekey');
}
```

Note: This is possible only if the lifetime of the store is same as the lifetime of the view. If you need to access a global store with a longer lifetime then assign it a storeId and get it with:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('theStoreId');
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I'm using MVVM archictecture for all the new code we write. I want access to a global store, because this holds all possible locales (languages) which I must access throughout the application lifetime, I use the getStore() method for this purpose now.

Answer (score 2):

Ext.getStore('storeIdHere') is one way to do it